# Check if a workItem's type is 'Feature'

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops, workitem

I'm trying to check if a `workItem` is a feature or not. I don't know what to compare the `workItem.Type` to in order to do this though.

Anybody know?

Comment: We'll need more information from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

`workItem.Type.Name` gives the name of the type. This results in the string `"Feature"`